# How to query without limiting the number of results returned?

Tags: javascript, ydn-db

It seems by default any query will only return up to 100 values.

ie:

```
db.values("mystore").done(function(myvalues) {
    // myvalues.length <= 100, regardless of how many items are in `mystore`
});
```

The docs refer to the API being `values(store_name, key_range, limit, offset, reverse)`, but apparently `null` is not a valid limit. Also `0` and `-1` just give me no results (or strangely, one result). How can I specify "unlimited results" without doing something silly like making the limit `999999`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unlimited result is not possible and its use is discouraged. Because your app will crash at some point.

If you want unlimitted result,  use streaming api such as `open` or `scan`.

Comment: Kyaw,

Is there any docs on just using db.open? When I do a search I don't see any basic usage examples. I saw some questions on SO about deleting records etc but none with simply pushing data out.

I really just need to push data to the screen no sorting etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the example in [open API doc](http://dev.yathit.com/api-reference/ydn-db/storage.html#open) not good enough?